# Concise python way to alter a value if its not Falsey

Tags: python, python-3.x

I often have this idiom (realistically long variable names chosen):

```
if variable_name:
    another_variable = " - " + variable_name
else:
    another_variable = variable_name
```

Its seems rather long and complicated for what its actually doing. 
I search stackoverflow thinking there must be a better way each time.

The following is the best I have come up with after research.

```
another_variable = " - " + variable_name if variable_name else variable_name
```

Or alternatively on two lines:

```
another_variable = variable_name 
if variable_name: another_variable = " - " + another_variable
```

Both options are okay, but not as concise and pythonic as I hope it could be. Just to put myself at rest so next time I come across it, I don't go down this
hole again: Is there a way putting the assignment on one line, without duplicating the variable names so much?

Comment: And what does `variable_name` hold? is it a string? an integer ? a float?

Comment: THis is fine. It's a bit of a strange thing to need and the variable names are a bit long, makes it look a bit clumsy, but I think all of those are fine (except the third, which doesn't actually do anything).

Comment: `another_variable = " - " + variable_name if variable_name else variable_name` is simple and pythonic. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Also if variable_name contains a string, and it's falsy, then that means it's `""`. So that it doesn't need to be added. That's a bit strange.

Comment: `another_variable = variable_name and '-' + variable_name`…?

Comment: Remember the mantra of Python, "Readability Counts" and "Simple is better than complex.". The `val if val else other` syntax is simple and easy to read. Nothing more "pythonic" than that.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh since its being added to a string, its likely a string. However the important part is to "alter a value if its not Falsey", what ever its type is.

Comment: Thanks guys the 3rd one did nothing, I corrected it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that i can think about of this is to use the and operator like this

```py
another_variable = variable_name and '-' + variable_name
```

[EDIT] : I didn't see it but deceze♦ as already posted this answer